# display multiple matching lines batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
:show 
cls  
echo ==============================  
echo =         Transactions       =  
echo ==============================  

set /p account_date=Enter the date of the transaction :   

set flag=0  

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /i /l /c:"!account_date!"  "log.txt"') do (  

if %%a==!account_date! (  
        echo Transaction date        Account name       amount  
        echo %%a                     %%b                %%c  
        set flag=1 

        )
if !flag!==0 echo Record was Not found   
PAUSE   
cls   
goto show       

)  

pause 

cls 

 1. List item

goto menu
```

I am trying to display all lines in a text file that match the date the user has inputted. For example if the user has inputted '2017-04-08' It would then display all lines with that date. But so far I have only been able to display the first matching line. How Would I display all matching lines?

> 2017-04-08 Faiz 2000
>   2017-04-08 Faiz 3000
>   2017-04-08 Faiz 1000

Comment: Because you have a `goto show` command _inside_ the `for` loop. You must move it _below_ the right parentheses...

Answer (score 0):

{revised body]

```
set /p account_date=Enter the date of the transaction :   
set "flag="

for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%a in ('findstr /i /l /c:"%account_date%"  "log.txt"') do (  

if %%a==%account_date% (  
   if not defined flag echo Transaction date        Account name       amount  
   echo %%a                     %%b                %%c  
   set flag=1
   )
)
if not defined flag echo Record was Not found   
PAUSE   
goto show
```

Comments:

The data you provide does not contain commas, so the `if %%a==!account_date!` should never have evaluated to `true`. You would need to change the `delims` character to a space to work with the data you've provided.

We have to assume that you've used `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`. Assuming is dangerous - please be explicit (ie. include the line to show you've thought of that point...)

Note that `!var!`==`%var%` outside of a `for` loop - and `!var!` only needs to be invoked if `var` is changed within the loop and you want to access the *changed* value. Hence no `!var!` is actually required in the snippet you've shown us.

Setting a variable to *nothing* means it's no longer defined. Setting it to *anything else* means it's defined. The `if defined` instructon interprets the *current status* of the variable. The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

So - the code first sets `flag` to *nothing*, then on the first match interprets `flag`. If it's not set, produce the header and set `flag` to *something*.

After the entire `for` loop has ben executed, `flag` will either be set or no, and so it can be used to produce the "no matches" message.

I'd suggest

```
set "account_date="
set /p account_date=Enter the date of the transaction :   
if not defined acount_date goto menu
set "flag="
```

Pressing just <kbd>Enter</kbd> in a `set /p` leaves the variable *unchanged* - it does not set it to *nothing*, so you need to do that first. With this code, you can detect just <kbd>Enter</kbd> to go back to your menu.